# Comment Stub generator for JsDuck in visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, documentation, comments, jsduck

I want to generate comment stubs for js methods in visual studio.

There is a comment stub generator called "JScript vsdoc Stub Generator" http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e122a031-d748-41e9-87b1-7b56d8610d8b

[image]

but i want to use JsDuck to generate documentation.

So it should be commented like below to use jsDuck

```
     /**
     * this is the description of the function
     */
    createPeopleView: function () {}
```

anyone know an extension for visual studio to get this done?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this problem?